# Atom not detecting python 2.7 is installed on Windows

Tags: python, atom-editor

Wanted to downgrade my python from 3.8 to 2.7, using the "script" package. but when I tried to run it, it gives me an error "Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store" after I uninstalled the later version of python.

on the terminal it could pull up python 2.7 just fine, with atom it doesn't seem to recognize it, even though I know it is in the environment PATH, I have restarted Atom multiple times.

Update: I solved my problem. Just had to uninstall Atom, delete the .Atom folder under the user folder in my local drive. Re-install Atom, and set up python again as normal

Comment: _using the "script" package_ Can you elaborate? What exactly did you do?

Comment: @AMC Script is a package that you can install for Atom that lets it run code 
https://atom.io/packages/script